# Convert a struct to bytes, save to file and read back to struct by another application in C#

Tags: c#, struct, arrays, marshalling

I tried writing structures to a binary file but I can't read them correctly.

This is my struct. It has a dynamic number of "values". If the number of values is 3, then GetSize() will return 8 + (8*3) = 32

```
[StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Sample
{
    public long timestamp;
    public double[] values;

    public int GetSize()
    {
        return sizeof(long) + sizeof(double) * values.Length;
    }
}
```

First, I convert the structure to bytes by:

```
public static byte[] SampleToBytes(Sample samp)
{
    int size = samp.GetSize();
    byte[] arr = new byte[size];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(samp, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    return arr;
}
```

Then, I write the bytes using BinaryWriter, and exit.
When I have to run the program again and read the file I saved. I use BinaryReader. I get every 32 bytes from the file and convert each array of 32 bytes back to struct using:

```
public static Sample BytesToSample(byte[] arr)
{
    Sample samp = new Sample();
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(32);
    Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, 32);
    samp = (Sample)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, samp.GetType());
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    return samp;
}
```

However, a SafeArrayTypeMismatchException occurs at PtrToStructure().
Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using the BinaryWriter to write the fields individually? All this copying between managed and unmanaged code doesn't bring you any advantage.

Comment: Or using Serialization with a BinaryFormatter - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0.aspx

Comment: Hi @dtb,
The main reason for not using BinaryFormatter is that the number of samples could reach more than 20M, so the file size would be larger than if I just write it as binary data.
Moreover, when the samples are placed in a list before serializing to a stream, OutOfMemory exception occurs. Do you think it would be faster and more efficient if I use the BinaryFormatter and save the data into several files instead of one?

Comment: I'm talking about [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx), not serialization/BinaryFormatter.

Comment: @dtb, About the BinaryWriter, I tried using it and I didn't have any problems. I was just thinking if there is a way not to loop through the values array using BitConverter.GetBytes() each. But if there's no other way, then I guess BinaryWriter is the way to go, or try BinaryFormatter and save into multiple files.

Comment: You can use the [BinaryWriter.Write Method (Double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez8wcba9.aspx) to write a double. No need for BitConverter, marshalling, serialization or anything else. Just use BinaryWriter.Write(double) to write and BinaryReader.ReadDouble() to read a value.

Comment: @dtb, Thanks. I used BinaryWriter/Reader Write/Read(Double) methods and proved to be faster by 1 minute than converting to/from bytes, on a file of 2.5G. I still need to loop through the double[]. But performance-wise, this would do for now.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that `double[]`, being an array type, is a **reference type**? The struct holds the `long` followed by a reference to the heap object.

That would be the reason why it doesn't work, I think.

I believe you should simply write the elements of your array to a binary writer.

Comment: Using BinaryWriter, is there a way to write the values of double[] into byte array without looping? Speed is a factor I'm considering, because data is expected to get very large.

Comment: See if a loop isn't performant enough. Like `foreach (var v in values) { yourWriter.Write(v); }`. It will be fast. You can also write it as `Array.ForEach(values, yourWriter.Write);` where the method group `Write` will be converted to a delegate. But I like the first way better. If this very fast solution is not fast enough, use `unsafe` and a pointer of type `double*`.